# why does this get method returning this message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I have this function that tabulates the user specific data. Its a get method that sends a query parameter userId:

```
<script>
            let thisArray = []
            let = userId = $('#userId').val();

            $.ajax({
                method:'GET',
                url:'/auth/marcacoesGET/:userId',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    userId: userId
                },
                success:function(marcacao){
                    thisArray = marcacao
                    buildTable(thisArray);
                    console.log(thisArray)      
                }
            })

            function buildTable(marcacao){
                let table = document.getElementById('tabelaCliente')

                for(let i = 0; i < marcacao.length; i++){
                    let row = `<tr>
                                    <td>${marcacao[i].address}</td>
                                    <td>${marcacao[i].date}</td>
                                    <td>${marcacao[i].hour}</td>
                                    <td>${marcacao[i].type}</td>
                                    <td>${marcacao[i].state}</td>
                               </tr>`
                    table.innerHTML += row
                }
            }
        </script>
```

I want this function to pass the userId to this get method:

This is a route

```
router.get('/marcacoesGET/:userId', authControllerMarcacao.getMarcacoes);
```

and this is the get method.

```
exports.getMarcacoes = async(req, res) => {
    
    const { userId } = req.params;
    try {
        const user = await User.findById({_id : userId}).populate('marcacaoCliente');
        console.log('user', user);
        res.status(200).json(user.marcacaoCliente);
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({message:err});
    }
```

And I got this weird message on the browser console, IDK if it's an error or not:

```
Object { message: {…} }
​
message: Object { stringValue: "\"{ _id: ':userId' }\"", kind: "ObjectId", path: "_id", … }
​​
kind: "ObjectId"
​​
path: "_id"
​​
reason: Object {  }
​​
stringValue: "\"{ _id: ':userId' }\""
​​
value: Object { _id: ":userId" }
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__()
​​
__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__()
​​
__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__()
​​
__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__()
​​
__proto__: 
​​
constructor: function Object()
​​
hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty()
​​
isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf()
​​
propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable()
​​
toLocaleString: function toLocaleString()
​​
toString: function toString()
​​
valueOf: function valueOf()
​​
<get __proto__()>: function __proto__()
​​
<set __proto__()>: function __proto__()
```

If you need more info pls tell

Comment: In ajax call shouldn't you provide user id instead of `:userId`? eg this `url:'/auth/marcacoesGET/:userId',` chage to this `url:'/auth/marcacoesGET/1',`

Comment: Indeed, you're requesting `/auth/marcacoesGET/:userId?userId=1`. However the client-side ajax URL you need is `"/auth/marcacoesGET/" + userId` The browser console output you're seeing is the error object from the server's db query.

Comment: @ciekals11 ok how do i make it so it reads the current log in user id?

Comment: You're asking how to insert a variable into a string... (actually append it, which is even simpler) Also, you should turn on the `xhr` filter in your browser console so you can double-check the ajax URL, request and response

Comment: `url:'/auth/marcacoesGET/' + userId` or `url: \`/auth/mamarcacoesGET/${userId}\``

Comment: Also this: `let = userId = $('#userId').val();` suprisingly works but is supposed to be `let userId = $('#userId').val();
`

Comment: @ciekals11 thank you all, but it seems that this userId variable I created in client-side doesnt actually store the user's id... What am I missing, can you help?

Comment: See Chris G latest answer, it's probably because of that.

Comment: You haven't provided us with the HTML part where your `input` that stores userId is so I think that we have nothing that will help us to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ciekals11 stated in the comments, you should directly put your `userId` in the URL, and not `:userId`.

An ajax GET request does not make any use of a `data` parameter (which is essentially a body to the request). GET is usually used to **retrieve** data, not sending it.

Edit: With string templating, you could do this

```
url : `/auth/marcacoesGET/${userId}`
```